# Can't set text in NSTextView from .xib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

Below is a simplistic Obj-C / Cocoa "hello world" window, which is initialized from within a Carbon app.  The .xib contains a NSWindow, which has an NSView containing the NSButton/NSButtonCell and a NSScrollView/NSTextView/NSScroller(s).

The code compiles and links with no warnings.  The window is displayed properly, with both objects (button and text field).  Pressing the button does indeed go to buttonWasPressed, and I receive no errors regarding bad selectors in Xcode's debugger.

But the text in the NSTextView is unchanged.

I THINK I have the proper outlet for myTextView connected.  Perhaps using replaceTextContainer is not a proper way to connect myTextView to textContainer?

SAD NOTE: my 30 years of C++ programming does not a smooth transition to Obj-C/Cocoa make...

```
@implementation DictionaryWindowController

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    // This is actually a separate Cocoa window in a Carbon app -- I load it from the NIB upon command from a Carbon menu event...
    NSApplicationLoad();
    if (![NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Cocoa Test Window.nib" owner:self]) {
        NSLog(@"failed to load nib");
    }

    if (self) {

        // textStorage is a NSTextStorage* in DictionaryWindowController (NSObject)
        textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:@""];

        NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
        [givenStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
        [layoutManager autorelease];

        NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize:NSMakeSize(kLargeWidthForTextContainer, LargeNumberForText)];
        [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
        [textContainer autorelease];

        // Is this how to "connect" the myTextView (NSTextView) from the .nib to the textStorage/layoutManager/textContainer?
        [myTextView replaceTextContainer:textContainer];

        [myTextView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(LargeNumberForText, LargeNumberForText)];
        [myTextView setSelectable:YES];
        [myTextView setEditable:YES];
        [myTextView setRichText:YES];
        [myTextView setImportsGraphics:YES];
        [myTextView setUsesFontPanel:YES];
        [myTextView setUsesRuler:YES];
        [myTextView setAllowsUndo:YES];

        // shouldn't I be able to set the string in the NSTextStorage instance and cause the NSTextView to change its text and redraw?
        [[textStorage mutableString] setString:@"Default text from initialization..."];

    }

    return self;
}



- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender {

    // Pressing the button DOES get to this point, but the NSTextView didn't change...
    [[textStorage mutableString] setString:@"After button press, this text should be the content of the NSTextView."];
}

@end
```

Comment: I should also mention -- I'm building with Xcode & Interface Builder 3.2.6, on 10.6.8.

Comment: I would just do setString on the NSTextView itself.

Comment: Mike -- you ARE correct, that setString on the NSTextView itself DOES work.  Still, I wonder why the NSTextStorage/NSLayoutManager/NSTextContainer method above doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're "editing the text storage behind the text view's back". See NSTextStorage's [-edited:range:changeInLength:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000369-BAJCCBCH) documentation. The docs are a bit vague here but I believe -setString: on the -mutableString you're requesting does not notify the text storage itself of a change (it only updates attribute runs, etc. when modified).

Call -edited:range:changeInLength: or use NSTextView's -setString: method as Mike C. recommended.